# How to convert String type to Class type in java

Tags: java

I want to print all the class names in a package and also to print the corresponding attributes and their data types in each package.

In one code, I am able to get the classnames in the form of string.
In another code I am able to get the attributes and their data types using `Classname.class.getAttribute();`

However I want to merge the two codes. Since in the first code I got the classnames in the form of string , I can't use `Classname.class.getAttribute()` since here `Classname` will be of type `String`.

So I want a method which will convert the "Classname" from `String` type to `Class` type.

I tried `Class.forName()` but it didn't work.

Comment: Please specify how Class.forName() "didn't work."

Comment: If Class.forName() didn't work, its very likely that a) the class name is not right b) you got an error message but didn't know what it meant so you ignored it. ;)

Comment: Post your error message! and post the code where you tried using `Class.forName()`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
Class<?> classType = Class.forName(className);
```

Make sure `className` is fully qualified class name like `com.package.class` Also, please share your error message that you see.

Comment: Yes, the className was not fully qualified.
Upon giving the fully qualified name, it worked :)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If the fully-qualified name of a class is available, it is possible to get the corresponding Class using the static method Class.forName().

Eg:

```
Class c = Class.forName("com.duke.MyLocaleServiceProvider");
```

> **Note:** Make sure the parameter you provide for the function is fully qualified class name like com.package.class

[Check here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html) for any reference.

**EDIT:**

You could also try using `loadClass()` method.

Eg:

```
 ClassLoader cl;
 Class c = cl.loadClass(name);
```

It is invoked by the Java virtual machine to resolve class references.

**Syntax:**

```
public Class<?> loadClass(String name)
                   throws ClassNotFoundException
```

[For details on ClassLoader check here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html)

[Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Reflection/ConvertagivenStringintotheappropriateClass.htm)
is an implementation of ClassLoader.

Answer (score 1):

Please try as following.

```
String str = "RequiredClassName";    
Class <?> Cref = Class .forName("PackageNaem."+str );
```