# Can i use a string variable as a datatype to create other variables in java

Tags: java, reflection

I use reflection to invoke a method as:

```
method.invoke(someObject, null);
```

The problem is, I want to use the value that this method returns without having it's data type known before hand. I have the knowledge of the data type in a string variable, say

```
String type = "String";
```

Is it possible to do something equivalent of this-

```
type variable = method.invoke(someObject, null)
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Why not just return it to an `Object`?

Comment: I want to do type specific operation. For e.g. if it was an integer, I will check if it is less than 0. How will I achieve this if it is just of Object data type?

Comment: What about `myObject.equals(Integer.valueOf(0))` ?

Comment: You must know something about the object coming in or else how do you know what method to invoke via reflection?

Comment: I believe this question has already been asked here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286871/how-to-convert-string-type-to-class-type-in-java

Comment: @MadConan I know that what method is to be invoked on the object but type of the data that the method will return is known to me only in terms of another variable.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Object type with `instanceof`.

```
Object o = method.invoke(...);
if(o instanceof Integer) {
    // Integer logic...
}
if(o instanceof YourType) {
    // YourType logic...
}
// and so on
```

Comment: Any non if way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this could work for you:

```
if(type.equals("String"){
    String o = (String) returnedObject;
} else if(type.equals("Integer")){
    Integer o = (Integer) returnedObject;
}
```

But I recommend not going down this road. There has to be some better way to achieve your desired result.

Comment: I also feel the same.