# Is there a way of parsing strings to class types from YAML?

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

I was wondering if there is any way of loading a YAML configuration like this:

```
classes:
  a: A.class
  b: B.class
```

in such a way that `A.class` and `B.class` can later be retrieved as `Class` type (something similar to `Map<String, Class>`

### **Update #1**

I'm using Spring Boot to load configuration in this class:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties
public class ClassesConfig {

    private Map<String, Class<?>> classes;

}
```

I could do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286871/how-to-convert-string-type-to-class-type-in-java), but I don't actually know how to achieve that while maintaining the use of this class...

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286871/how-to-convert-string-type-to-class-type-in-java) out. Not an exact duplicate but good inspiration.

Comment: does it have to be yaml? afaicr springboot natively supports defining some objects in xml

Comment: @JoSSte unfortunately, yes

Comment: Maybe [conditional properties](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-conditional-annotations) is a good match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationPropertiesBinding
public class ClassConverter implements Converter<String, Class<?>> {

    @Override
    public Class<?> convert(String from) {
        return Class.forName(from);
    }
}
```

Tweak it according to your needs; for example, if you want the `.class` suffix in the YAML file, remove that from the string `from` because it is not part of the class name.

Mind that you need to give the fully qualified name of the class. So if `A` and `B` are in a package, you need to give that package as prefix.